# Rebuilding ExternalProject with changes

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to test some of my modifications in the downloaded library using CMake + Visual Studio, but it is impossible due to all my changes are overwritten by the downloaded code.

Is it possible to rebuild a project imported with `ExternalProject_Add` command without downloading it?

Comment: Maybe you want to put your patches somewhere and use the PATCH_COMMAND parameter.

Comment: I know PATCH_COMMAND parameter, but first I have to discover what should I change. Doing it with patches is very uncomfortable.